# Passing data to servlet through button in jsp

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have a database with products. When I accept one of them I want to pass its id to a servlet. I accept or deny them using two buttons (Accept, Deny). How can I pass the id to my servlet?

Don't forget that there are many products, let's say five of them. How can I be sure what id I send to my servlet? Here is some part of my code:

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${productList}" >
    <div id="box">
        <div id="box_info">
            ${product.id}<br />
            ${product.name}<br />
            ${product.category}<br />
            ${product.currently}<br />
            ${product.currently}<br />
            ${product.firstbid}<br />
            ${product.numberofbids}<br />
            ${product.location}<br />
            ${product.country}<br />
            ${product.description}<br />
        </div>

        <div id="box_buttons">
            <a href="Myservlet1"><div id="box_button" class="accept">Accept</div></a>
             <a href="Myservlet2"><div id="box_button" class="deny">Deny</div></a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: A more modern approach would leverage jQuery and attach a click handler to make an AJAX request to an HTTP listener.  The HTTP request could be a GET with the id as a parameter in the URL.  It would make the servlet look like a REST service.

Comment: Could i use Httpsession ? For example session.setAttribute("id",id); . I have to mention that I already use httpsession setting there the username. Can i delete only the id from my session and leave there being the username?

Comment: You need to submit the HTML form or, like @duffmymo says, use AJAX.

Comment: There is no submit and no form. But i see your point. Now i undestand. I need some doGet.

Comment: No, session has nothing to do with it.   Should be idempotent - REST.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the `<a href...>` into submit buttons. Everything is cool now. Here are the changes.

```
<c:forEach var="product" items="${productList}" >
    <div id="box">
        <div id="box_info">
            ${product.id}<br />
            ${product.name}<br />
            ${product.category}<br />
            ${product.currently}<br />
            ${product.currently}<br />
            ${product.firstbid}<br />
            ${product.numberofbids}<br />
            ${product.location}<br />
            ${product.country}<br />
            ${product.description}<br />
        </div>

        <div id="box_buttons">
            <form>
            <input type="hidden" name="product_id" value=${product.id} />
            <input type="submit" value="deny" name="act" id="box_button" class="accept">
            <input type="submit" value="accept" name="act" id="box_button" class="deny">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: That works, too.  Time to consider giving up JSP and learning HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, jQuery, and REST services.  That's where the world has gone.

Comment: @duffymo I use jsp because i need to create a web application. Some modifies and it will be an application for smart phones. My purpose here is not to create a web site.

Comment: How are HTML5, CSS3, JavaScript, jQuery and REST not about web apps?  No difference at all.  Better learn about modern application development.

Comment: I don't think you undestand me. How can you turn it into an application by using html , css, ... and not java?

Comment: I don't think you understand me, Java, JSP, or web applications.  You're free to have a Java back end - by all means.  Java need not appear on the front end.  The browser doesn't know anything about Java - just HTML, CSS, and Javascript.  What happens when you use JSP?  What does it do?  (Hint: It's an HTML factory.)

Comment: Again you don't undestand. How can you turn your webapp into an application (NOT web) without java. Application by its own doesn't need a browser.